# Find all integer solutions $(x,y)$ such that $2^x+2^y=x^2+y^2$

Tags: number-theory

when i saw this question "if $2^x + 2^y = x^2 + y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative integers, what is the greatest possible value of $|x – y|$?" I wanted to figure out what are all the integer values that can satisfy that equation.

I thought on testing trivial values, starting with non-negative integers. I figured out that $x=y=2$ and $x=4,y=2$ would satisfy the equation, but testing integers one by one seems to be tricky.

Comment: Any ideas of your own?

Comment: i I thought on testing trivial values, starting with non-negative integers. I figured out that $x=y=2$ and $x=4$ with $y=2$ would satisfy the equation, but testing integers one by one seems to be tricky

Answer (score 3):

$$2^x+2^y=x^2+y^2$$
$$2^x-x^2=-(2^y-y^2)$$
For $x=0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots$, $2^x-x^2=1,1,0,-1,0,7,\dots$ and the difference only grows larger from there. We seek two values that are negatives of each other, as far apart as possible; those are $x=0$ and $x=3$, so the largest $|x-y|$ is $3$, attained by $x=0,y=3$:
$$2^0+2^3=9=0^2+3^2$$